# rhandsontable dropdown menu multiple selection

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to make an interactive table in Shiny, and for one of the columns I would like to have an option to select multiple values from the dropdown menu.

A simple piece of code (package 'rhandsontable' is required):

```
require(rhandsontable)
DF = data.frame(val = 1:10,
            factor = factor(rep("h1",10), levels =  c("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9","h10","h11","h12","h13","h14","h15","h16","h17","h18","h19","h20","h21","h22","h23","h24"), ordered = TRUE )
            )
rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300)
```

My aim is to be able to select multiple lines in the 'factor' column, so that the row would read, for example: 'h1','h2','h3'.

I am wondering, if that's even possible; I could work around it if I had an input as a character string, but then the user would have to manually type in the required values, which increases the probability of an error as well as decreases user-friendliness.

Thanks in advance, Matija

PS: I have tired with setting type on hot_col to 'select' (see the below code), which should solve the problem (I think), but it doesn't even execute...

```
rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
 hot_col(col = "factor", type = "select", source = LETTERS)
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible but in the meantime you could use this as an alternative: rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL, width = 900, height = 300) %>%
    hot_col(col = "factor", type = "dropdown", source = c("h1, h2", "h1,h2, h3", "h1, h2, h3, h4"))

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, but unfortunately it doesn't work as I would wish - I would like to enable user to pick any subset of 24 values, which is a bit too much to list .. I am already through with my text input though, I think I Will stick to it unless i find a better solution. Thanks again, Matija